# How to determine butt coupling loss between waveguide and fiber?

Tags: optics

How to determine the butt coupling loss for a single mode 632 nm fiber and waveguide written on fused silica?

Comment: It would be good to have a decent answer to this question (or one like it) on stack exchange.